# Pysal OLS function can not show summary output

Tags: python, economics, pysal

I tried PYSAL library in python for Basic OLS method, I followed official documentation from pysal library and for some reason summary for OLS can be shown it says 'str' object has no attribute 'summary'

```
YVar='cena'
XVars = ["km", "stari", "diesel"]

Y=data[YVar].as_matrix().reshape((len(data),1))
X=data[XVars].as_matrix()


ols=ps.model.spreg.OLS(Y,X,name_y=YVar, name_x=XVars,nonspat_diag=True, white_test=True)
# till here it works perfectly



print("ols".summary())
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to print `ols` variable, but you are trying to print `"ols"` as a text string. Quotation marks should not be there.

```
print(ols.summary())
```